# How to read CakePHP Model using specific fields?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm new to CakePHP and I'm stuck in reading a Model using other fields. I did a cake bake command to generate a simple users CRUD. I can view the user using the url CakePHP provided.

```
/users/view/1
```

I can view the user using id = 1. What if I want to view a user by name instead of id?

```
/users/view/username
```

By default the view function reads the User model by id.

```
$this->User->read(null, $id)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `find` function or `findBy<Field>()` in your case `findByUsername()`

[check this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1026/findBy)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used cakePHP myself but I'm going to suggest that you will likely have to implement a new user model method, something like getUserByUsername($username)
This would then in turn interface with your DAL that would get the details of that user based on the username and return a user object that can be used however you wish...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CakePHP is focusing to deprecate some functions, such as `findAll()`. Perhaps soon the magic methods such as `findBy<field>()` will have the same fate.

I can recommend what martswite is suggesting, you should create your custom function:

```
function findUser($username=''){
    return $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.username' => $username
        )
    ));
}
```

Perhaps you have a `status` field, maybe the profile isn't public, you can add a condition:

```
function findUser($username=''){
    return $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.username' => $username,
            'User.status' => 1
        )
    ));
}
```

I think that's more modular than `findBy<Field>`.

Comment: "It seems that CakePHP is focusing to deprecate some functions, such as findAll(). Perhaps soon the magic methods such as findBy<field>() will have the same fate"
Where did you read from that these functions are going to be deprecated?